# mktime() in C is returning -1 (always)

Tags: c, datetime, mktime

I've a snippet here: http://ideone.com/fywv3J

Posting it here also :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int gtime_to = 20131231;

int main() {
  time_t current_time, licence_expiry_time;
  struct tm licence_expiry_time_struct;
  memset(&licence_expiry_time_struct, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_mday = gtime_to % 100;                  // get the day
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_mon = ((gtime_to % 10000) / 100) - 1;   // get the month
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_year = gtime_to / 10000;                // get the year
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_hour = 0;
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_min = 0;
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_sec = 0;
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_wday = 0;
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_yday = 0;
  licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_isdst = -1;
  licence_expiry_time = mktime(&licence_expiry_time_struct);
  time(&current_time); 
  printf("date = %d, month = %d, year = %d\n", licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_mday, licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_mon, licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_year);
  printf("cur = %d, expiry = %d, diff = %d", current_time, licence_expiry_time, difftime(licence_expiry_time, current_time));
  return 0;
}
```

The output of **mktime()** is **-1** for every possible value I've tried with.

This is the line
`cur = 1386084345, expiry = -1, diff = -25165824`
where the value of **expiry** shouldn't be **-1**. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Paste the code in your question.

Comment: Hint: what format specifier have you used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your year should be an offset since 1900. That's most probably the culprit.

Try:

```
licence_expiry_time_struct.tm_year = gtime_to / 10000 - 1900;
```

In general, when using `mktime()` it's highly recommended to start with a valid `tm` structure in the first place (i.e. by calling `localtime()`) and then changing the fields.

Comment: @dibyendu: Calling this a "*trick*" I feel is ineptly. This is a well documented feature, you could have come accross your own, if you 'd have Read The Fuxxxxx Manual: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM.